# Scrolling in Native "Web" App

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, scroll

I've been developing native iOS apps for 2 years now. As some customers need iOS, Android and Winphone support, i decided to play around with WebApps (HTML, JQuery mobile,..) and PhoneGap.
Everything works like a charm, but now i'm getting some problems.

I want to create a native-app like feeling, but as you can see in the images attached below when i scroll down, the header always scrolls with the screen.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Best regards,
Lukas

[image]

[image: None]

EDIT: I'm searching for a JS solution. (If possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more solutions to achive, what i wanted to do. I just want to add the following info for other's searching for a solution. If you use phonegab, you can add the following code to your config.xml in order to disable the bouncing.

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, add `webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;`

This will take care of the "bouncy" webView, and will prevent the user from scrolling beyond the top of the page.

Comment: Hello, thank's for your solution. I already tried this and it work's fine, but i'm searching a javascript solution for this. Is there a way to achive this in JS or is this simply no possible? If not i will accept your answer :)

Comment: If you're targeting an iOS solution, this works for a native app. If you're wanting this to also work via the web (using JS) it's not "cleanly possible" as the different browsers on mobile devices handle the scroll differently. I'd stick with this if you're mainly concerned with the native app :)

Comment: Yes i used this option, but in another way. There is a option for the bouncing in phonegap, which work's for all plattforms :) I answer my question for myself, because maybe there is also someone else searching for it! But thank's for your answer!